# Kibana Visualization: creating a bar graph with fields in JSON document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

New to Kibana visualizations here...

I'm planning on publishing a JSON (once a day) that has populations of list of cities. Following is a sample JSON:

```
{ 
   "timestamp":"2019-10-10",
   "population_stats":[ 
      { 
         "city":"New York",
         "population":8398748
      },
      { 
         "city":"Los Angeles",
         "population":3976322
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to setup cities in the X axis and population count in Y axis.

I can setup my X axis property (with Field aggregations) however I just can't get the populations to reflect in the Y axis.

Using "count" in the Y axis always gives me 1 -- I guess this is because there's only one document for the given date range.

Is there a proper way to get the correct population count to display on the Y axis?

Comment: Now that I think about, in order to correctly reflect the population count in Y-axis, I think I need that many data points in Elastic (i.e. that # of JSON documents available in Elastic)?

Comment: Hi @AlphaNumerical, can you share your index mapping ? Had a similar issue a few years ago with Kibana not handling nested data properly.

Comment: @baitmbarek I didn't define index mappings for this index. I don't think it matters, does it?

Comment: As far as I can remember it was a mapping issue allowing Kibana to retrieve nested fields. I'll be playing with this to reproduce and suggest you a solution

Comment: Kibana can detect nested fields property - that's how I managed to correctly get the cities to display on the X-axis.  However can't do similar (i.e. get population counts) for Y-axis

Comment: Reading the docs ... Kibana continue saying they don't support nested objects (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/nested-objects.html). I don't feel confident for this :(

Comment: @baitmbarek managed to figure this out. You're correct about Kibana not detecting inner fields, so you basically have to create a JSON for each city. And then from visualizations, you need to select "sum" or "average" aggregation type.

Comment: thanks for the feedback ! Glad you made it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to figure this out!

Folks are correct about Kibana not being able detecting inner fields, so you basically have to create a JSON for each city (going by my example in the question above). And then from visualizations, you need to select "sum" or "average" aggregation-type. That's all!

Comment: could you elaborate please "create a JSON for each city" ? What did you change in your original dictionary in the first message ? thanks

Comment: So instead of creating one Json that has all the cities in an array, create a Json for each city. If you have 5  cities then create and persist 5 Json docs in index